# Change a single icon in the Unity launcher panel?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons

I have a third-party application, (in this case, Oracle SQLDeveloper which is a java application), that I installed manually (i.e. not through apt).  When I ran it, I selected to "Lock to Launcher" so I can easily launch it again.  The icon works to launch the application, but the icon is a generic grey question mark icon.  I can download various other icons that would be more appropriate, but I don't see any way to customize just a single icon in the launcher.

Comment: please look inside your `~/.local/share/applications` folder to see if there is a representing `.desktop` file of the application. (If not, look in `/usr/share/applications`) If so, could you open it with gedit (drag it over a gedit window) and post the line starting with `Icon=` (or better: the whole file). There can be various reasons why an icon does not appear properly in the launcher.

Comment: [Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Name=Oracle SQL Developer 
Icon=.png
Path=/opt/sqldeveloper/sqldeveloper/bin
Exec=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java .....

Comment: Should I be able to directly edit the "Icon=.png" line?  If so, how do I update it and/or make it stick?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From your comment, it turns out that there is no icon defined in the `.desktop` file. You can use an icon "of your choice", and edit the line:

```
Icon=.png
```

to:

```
Icon=/path/to/your/icon.png
```

You will possibly have to log out and back in to make the change appear.

*Note1*

If you found your `.desktop` file in `/usr/share/applications`, it is good practice to first copy it to `~/.local/share/applications` and edit the local copy. After log out / in, the local version will "overrule" the one in `/usr/share/applications`.

Both Dash and the Unity Launcher will then use the local one.

*Note2*

You might want to look inside the application's directory (which seems to be `/opt/sqldeveloper`) if there is not already an appropriate icon to use. `/opt` is a typical directory where self-contained "all in one" applications can be located.

Comment: It turned out that I had it in .local and when I updated the Icon=/opt/sqldeveloper/icon.png, it showed up instantly without logging out.

Answer (score 0):

I use a program called "Main Menu" or "Alacarte"

To Install:

`sudo apt-get install alacarte`

Then open Main Menu through the dash.