# Changing a dock's icon image

Tags: dock

I'm having difficulty changing a program's dock icon. I was following the [instructions here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/556287/change-a-single-icon-in-the-unity-launcher-panel), and I think the problem rests with my program.desktop's pathing. This program isn't "installed" and it rests in my documents folder. Here's the file I have added to /usr/share/applications

```
[Desktop Entry]   
Name=prog    
Comment=Explain me here!    
Icon=/home/garrisonxci/Documents/Jaxx/resources/app/img   
Exec=/home/garrisonxci/Documents/prog/prog.exe
Terminal=false   
Type=Application   
Categories=Other  
StartupNotify=true
```

The icon still shows up as the generic grey question mark.

Comment: Does the Icon name iclude the file extension `.png` / `.jpg` ... ?

Comment: A few things don't make sense: the application cannot be a .exe and, as my upper neighbour mentions, if you use full path to the icon, it needs the extension. Possibly other issues play a role. Please mention the application and the *actual* content of the .desktop file. The posted info is not sufficient.

Comment: The icon name is a .png, the application is Jaxx.

That *is* the actual content of the .desktop, I created it from instructions linked in the OP.